# Books explaining 'Physical Significance' of Physics Quantities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, resource-recommendations

As a high school student with an avid interest in Physics, I find it difficult & useless to read Physics from my prescribed textbooks.

Because they lack a detailed explanation of the phenomena around us & miss the significance of physical quantities. In simple words, it teaches me to chug & plug formulas-values in the equations without any proper understanding.

Surely, I do take help from the web such as this website; but things aren't very well-arranged here on the web.

A book containing the physical significances & the meanings of basic physical quantities (from fields like Mechanics, Electrodynamics, QM, Thermodynamics etc) will certainly help me understand these things. Unfortunately, I haven't come across such a book until now even after doing a hectic search.

As for now, I study the basics of these fields- Electrodynamics, Thermodynamics, QM, Optics, Mechanics, Solid-State Physics etc; but find it difficult to digest many formulas, understand why they even exist or what they actually mean/hold.

A prescription of book/books to solve my problem will help a lot in keeping my fascination in Physics alive.

Comment: It might help if you said which books you've read but found unhelpful, since it would give us an idea of what explanatory strategies are _not_ working for you. For example, you say you don't understand why certain equations hold, but it takes what I'll euphemistically call a very special kind of textbook to leave their cause unclear.

Answer (score 1):

My list would be e.g.:

Pohl’s Introduction to Physics, Volume 1 and 2 covering Mechanics, Acoustics and Thermodynamics, Electrodynamics and Optics, Springer

Wolfgang Demtröder - Atoms, Molecules and Photons  An Introduction to Atomic-, Molecular- and Quantum Physics, Springer

Wolfgang Nolting - Theoretical Physics, books 1-6  from Mechanics to QM, Springer

Charles Kittel - Introduction to Solid State Physics, Wiley